# How can I find where the GD function `stringFT` is defined?

Tags: perl, gd

I'm having a problem with some code I've inherited that uses [`GD`](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD): sometimes the function `stringFT` returns an error. I'd like to debug this function, but I can't find where it is defined in the `GD` source code.

I've searched in all the files under the `GD` folder in my Perl installation and the only reference to that function is in `GD/Image.pm`:

```
*stringTTF = \&GD::Image::stringFT;
```

How can I find where this function is defined so I can debug it?

Comment: GD.pm is simply an interface to libgd, which is written in C, so I don't think there is Perl code implementing that function anywhere. [`gdImageStringFT`](http://www.boutell.com/gd/manual2.0.9.html#gdImageStringFT) is the name of the C function that `stringFT` corresponds to. I know next to nothing about calling C code from Perl, but perhaps this PerlMonks thread will help: [How can I debug perl-xs code?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=326559)

Comment: FYI `stringFT` can be found in GD.xs -- if you fancy trying a bit of C, that's what you need to hack! ;)